# how to get previous element with jquery each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know the each function iterates over an array. Is there way to access the indice like (this[i])? I need to be able compare current element's pubDate with the previous element's pubDate and if it's different output a new pubdate.

```
    $(data).find('item').each(function(i, value){
            var title = $(this).find('title').text().replace(/\w+\s+\(.*?\)/, "");
            var link = $(this).find('link').text();
            var pubDate = $(this).find('pubDate').text();
            alert(title); 
            alert(link);
            alert(pubDate);
            $('#events').append("<p>" + title + "<br/>" + link + "</p>");

        });
```

Answer (score 8):

One of many potential ways would be:

```
var previous = null;
$(data).find('item').each(function(i, value){
        if (previous) {
            ... do stuff with previous element ...
        }

        var title = $(this).find('title').text().replace(/\w+\s+\(.*?\)/, "");
        var link = $(this).find('link').text();
        var pubDate = $(this).find('pubDate').text();
        alert(title); 
        alert(link);
        alert(pubDate);
        $('#events').append("<p>" + title + "<br/>" + link + "</p>");

        previous = this;
    });
```

You have to check to see if previous is not null, since the first iteration will contain a null value (the first element doesn't have any previous element).

Comment: Since it's a pretty specific thing to the each, I recommend throwing it all into a `(function(){ //code by shanked // }())` which will keep `previous` out of the scope of anything else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
var previousDate = $(this).prev().find('pubDate');
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use this and traverse

for example

```
this.parent()
```

gives you the index

or

```
i in your loop
```